# Remove and adding forward slash when serializing Path in Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I am working with two APIs. One has all its paths with leading forward slashes, and the other does not. I have decided to normalize my application and use a leading forward slash for all paths (since none of the paths are relative).

If I submit JSON to API with non leading slash, with a value used for a path that has leading slash on the path, it will produce an error.

Is there any way to modify the following class so that, when it is deserialized, the Path has a leading slash, and when serialized it has no leading slash, just for this specific POJO?

```
public class FilePOJO {
    @JsonProperty("path")
    public Path path;
}
```

e.g.

```
FilePOJO fp = new FilePOJO();
fp.path = Paths.get("/some/path/file.txt");
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(fp));
// {"path": "some/path/file.txt"}
final FilePOJO filePOJO = om.readValue("{\"path\": \"some/path/file.txt\"}", FilePOJO.class);
System.out.println(filePOJO.path.toString());
// /some/path/file.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding getters and setters to your POJO which are used while serialization and deserialization. Below is one way of doing it.

```
@JsonProperty("path")
public Path getPath() {
    return Paths.get(path.toString().substring(1));
}

@JsonProperty("path")
public void setPath(Path path) {
    this.path = Paths.get("/", path.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I copied your code, then renamed the `getPath` to `getPathInAPIForm`, then added a `getPath` method that returns the unaltered path (without the JsonProperty annotation). This means I can use getPath in my program and get the actual path, but then the serialized json will produce the altered path. Not sure if this is best practice or not.